# Complex Scenario Teradata Query From Single Table

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, scenarios, teradatasql

QUESTION :

Fetch the records that are having type='Onsite Repair' as well as the records that have
Type in ('Calibration', 'Interface Troubleshooting', 'Setup/Configuration','Customer Applications') only when there is also a row with Type='Travel' within the same Act_ID on the same date. Else ignore. (Record with onsite repair type should always appear)

**Type = "Onsite Repair"
OR
Type = ("Calibration", "Interface Troubleshooting", "Setup/Configuration","Customer Applications") only when there is also a row with Type="Travel" within the same Act_ID on the same date. Else ignore the Types.**

- **SOURCE DATA**

| ACT_ID | TYPE | START_TS | END_TS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACTID1 | Travel | 7/20/2016 13:00 | 7/20/2016 15:30 |
| ACTID1 | Interface Troubleshooting | 7/20/2016 15:30 | 7/20/2016 19:00 |
| ACTID1 | Travel | 7/20/2016 19:00 | 7/20/2016 21:00 |
| ACTID1 | Travel | 9/20/2016 13:00 | 9/20/2016 15:30 |
| ACTID1 | Onsite Repair | 9/20/2016 15:30 | 9/20/2016 23:30 |
| ACTID1 | Travel | 9/21/2016 13:00 | 9/21/2016 15:30 |
| ACTID1 | Onsite Repair | 9/21/2016 15:30 | 9/21/2016 23:30 |
| ACTID1 | Travel | 9/22/2016 13:00 | 9/22/2016 15:30 |
| ACTID1 | Onsite Repair | 9/22/2016 15:30 | 9/22/2016 23:30 |

- **EXPECTED DATA**

| ACT_ID | TYPE | START_TS | END_TS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ACTID1 | Interface Troubleshooting | 7/20/2016 15:30 | 7/20/2016 19:00 |
| ACTID1 | Onsite Repair | 9/20/2016 15:30 | 9/20/2016 23:30 |
| ACTID1 | Onsite Repair | 9/21/2016 15:30 | 9/21/2016 23:30 |
| ACTID1 | Onsite Repair | 9/22/2016 15:30 | 9/22/2016 23:30 |

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to do just this bit: _Fetch the records that are having type='Onsite Repair' as well as the records that have Type in ('Calibration', 'Interface Troubleshooting', 'Setup/Configuration','Customer Applications')_

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, I wrote below query and its works but i'm looking for more simple query instead of performing self join. SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE TYPE = 'Onsite Repair' UNION SELECT * FROM TABLE A INNER JOIN TABLE B ON A.ACT_ID = B.ACT_ID WHERE A.PROJ_NAM IN ('Calibration', 'Interface Troubleshooting', 'Setup/Configuration','Customer Applications') AND B.TYPE='Travel' AND CAST(A.START_TS AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') = CAST(B.START_TS AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple task for a *Windowed Aggregate* plus qualify:

```
select *
from table
qualify Type = 'Onsite Repair'
     OR (Type = in ('Calibration','Interface Troubleshooting', 'Setup/Configuration','Customer Applications')
        -- row with Type='Travel'
          AND count(case when Type='Travel' then 1 end)
                         -- same Act_ID on the same date
              over (partition by Act_ID, cast(START_TS as date)  > 0
        )
```

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. This answer set of the query exactly matches with the query answer set that i have written and i believe is correct.
Can you help me understand the processing of the qualify part.
I know qualify works like filter condition but i'm more curious on how this part is processed (Type = in ('Calibration','Interface Troubleshooting', 'Setup/Configuration','Customer Applications')
          AND count(case when Type='Travel' then 1 end)
              over (partition by Act_ID, cast(START_TS as date)) > 0

Comment: QUALIFY is processed *after* WHERE/GROUP BY/HAVING and the **Group Count** applies aggregate logic without loosing detail rows.